# mssql_connect no longer working as of PHP 5.3

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2005, php-5.3, deprecated

I just received an email from our host and they've upgraded our PHP to 5.3, unfortunately though, all the scripts have now broken. I traced it down to the function **mssql_connect** failing. Support told me this has now been deprecated under 5.3 - how can this be true?

How can you connect to a mssql database under PHP 5.3 now??

Comment: [Recommended method](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php) - [Other method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx) (although they both use the same driver, PDO is "the PHP way")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php

"This extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or later."

Maybe you should look into converting your app to use PDO:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php

Comment: I think he knows that. This doesn't answer the `How can you connect to a mssql database under PHP 5.3 now?` question though, which is what really matters.

Answer (score 0):

If you see such a warning, the first place to visit is the PHP documentation.

From http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php:

> Introduction
>
> These functions allow you to access MS SQL Server database.
>
> This extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or
>   later.
>
> SQLSRV, an alternative driver for MS SQL is available from Microsoft:
>   » http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx.