# Connect to MSSQL Server via PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I have MSSQL 2008 installed on my production server. I want to operate on that data remotely via php. As I went through a lot of articles and installed 'php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll' and 'php_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll' files in my ext folder and enable them in my php.ini file. But still I am getting following error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()...

Please help me out how could I do this?

Comment: Check your extension dir value in php.ini

Comment: It sounds like you either need to enable the MSSQL server in your php.ini (From memory, it isn't enabled by default) or you should modify your code to use PDO, which I am pretty sure allows connections to MSSQL without any hassles.

Comment: May be this (see answers) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244470/mssql-connect-no-longer-working-as-of-php-5-3 as @Fluffeh says PDO is the way forward

Comment: @neoistheone - the are extensions, not libraries. Also, OP is calling the wrong one. It's sqlsrv_connect. mssql is older extension, no longer supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`php_sqlsrv_54_ts` is not the extension files for the `mssql` extension, which is no longer supported when connecting from PHP hosted on Windows. `php_sqlsrv_54_ts` is for [`SQLSRV`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php) and you need to connect using [`sqlsrv_connect`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php).

Just in case the above is less than clear... You have the right extension installed, meaning the one that is newer and preferred. You are using the wrong functions. You don't need to, nor should you, try to enable the `mssql` extension. You simple need to use the `sqlsrv` extension functions instead.

Comment: I have installed the same files. Now I am using sqlsrv_connect function. Now I am getting following error.
Connection could not be established.
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -49 [code] => -49 [2] => This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712
Let me tell you that I am trying to connect it remotely on mssql server.